# Javascript Json Jquery Basics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

today, i learned the basics of Json and its parsing through Jquery. I know my question is futile but i am stuck and unable to get a way out.

the following code doesn't work....but i guess i did everything ok

```
<html>
<head>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=2d34860785184c2e3458de2bc437ecfc&tags=rose&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=b7303e1d0d8a9fbb1159404ca7927e98",function(data){
var output="<ul>";
for (var i in data.photos) {
    output+="<li>" + data.photos.photo[i].id+"</li>";


    if (i === 3){
    return false;
}
}
output+="</ul>";

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
})
})
</script>
</head>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you post an error from the javascript console?

Comment: Why is your `placeholder` div inside the <head> of the document instead of the <body>?

Comment: I guess you *didn't* do everything ok if it doesn't work.

Comment: If you used indentation it'd be incredibly much easier to figure out everything.

Comment: if you use jquery,use the $("#id") selector..not getElementById

Comment: also `return false;` looks like you meant `break;` instead

Comment: that was a mistake...but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your indexes wrong in the **JSON** you need to make the following changes.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ALJkV/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=2d34860785184c2e3458de2bc437ecfc&tags=rose&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=b7303e1d0d8a9fbb1159404ca7927e98", function (data) {
        var output = "<ul>";
        for (var i in data.photos.photo) { // The photo index is what you need;

            // If you want to skip 3
            if (i == 3) continue;
            // Or if you want to stop at 3 
            if(i == 3) break;

            output += "<li>" + data.photos.photo[i].id + "</li>";
        }
        output += "</ul>";

        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
    });
});
```

**Continue: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)**

Comment: why the hell `continue`?

Comment: `continue` does absolutely nothing here. I assume the OP wants to limit the loop to max 4 photos.

Comment: @MightyPork I don't understand why you would get thousands of photos in JSON from Flickr when you only want 3, i think he just want's to skip **3**

Comment: the way you did it, you will **not skip anything**. Either remove the `continue` or replace it with `break`.

Comment: Also, `i` is a string so `i === 3` is always false.

Comment: @MightyPork replacing `continue` with `break` won't do anything either

Comment: For that matter, `data.photos.photo[i].id` ought to be `i.id`, right?

Comment: @MightyPork this is not the code review site. I have just explained in the answer what is preventing this from working

Comment: Even if it isn't, posting buggy code as answer is **not** what we do here.

Comment: @user609306 Just make a counting variable before the `for`, and in each iteration add 1 and check, if it's 3. If yes, then `break`.

Comment: @MightyPork - regarding your suggestion about using `i.id`, no, that would _not_ work. `i` is the index/key not the associated value, so that would give an error.

Comment: @MightyPork buggy... ha..ha

Comment: On the `return false;` idea, that won't just exit the loop, it'll exit the entire function before it has actually put them in the placeholder element. Use `break;` to exit the loop without exiting the function.

Comment: @Connor okay I thought too highly of JavaScript's logic, my fault; But your `return false;` is indeed a stupid suggestion.

Comment: @MightyPork You have a valid point when you show me **where i suggested** `return false;`, it is what OP had, i never suggested it.

Comment: I swear I saw it in your answer, but let's not start a flamewar. Let's call this thread closed.

Comment: It was in my answer, that doesn't mean i suggested it.